# calling switch statement from outside of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have kind of big switch statement for my weather app and I got a lot of ids going on and I found it makes my main file so big so I wanted to make a file for all of my switch statement and call it in my component but I could not

here is the switch code

```
export   function switchCode (id){
switch(id){
    case 200:
    case 201:
    case 202:
    case 210:
    case 211:
    case 212:
    case 221:
    case 230:
    case 231:
    case 232: 
     console.log('thunder_icon');
       break;

     case 300:
     case 301:
     case 302:
     case 310:
     case 311:
     case 312:
     case 313:
     case 314:
     case 321:
     console.log('cloud rainy');
       break;

     case 500:
     case 501:
     case 502:
     case 503:
     case 504:
     case 511:
     case 520:
     case 521:
     case 522:
     case 531:
     console.log('rainy with sun');
         break;

     case 600:
     case 601:
     case 602:
     case 611:
     case 612:
     case 615:
     case 616:
     case 620:
     case 621:
     case 622:
     console.log('snow icon');
         break;

     case 701:
     case 711:
     case 721:
     case 731:
     case 741:
     case 751:
     case 761:
     case 762:
     case 771:
     case 781:
     console.log('hot icon or just sun or fog');
       break;

     case 800:
     console.log('big sunny');
      break;

     case 801:
     case 802:
     case 803:
     case 804:
     console.log('sun with cloud');
       break;

  }}
```

I tried to access as {this.props.switchCode(500)} and didn't work, just gave me blank space.
please, guys, help 
thanks

Comment: How are you calling it? That's not how you import it.

Comment: I tried like this (import {switchCode} from './switch_weather_codes';) and then in the code (this.props.switchCode(id))

Comment: You don't do `this.props.switchCode(id)`, you just need to do `switchCode(id)`

Comment: @BenAbed you are importing the function, so you need to access that directly like `switchCode(id)`, it will not be the part of props.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman @ Mayank Shukla  big thank you guys for your help,  I appreciate it thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you are importing the function `switchCode` using:

```
import {switchCode} from './switch_weather_codes';
```

**The `switchCode` function is available as a local variable.** You just need to access it using:

```
switchCode(id);
```

Note that this will just call the `console.log()` function. If you really need the value inside that, change the `console.log()` to `return`.

When you try to use `this.props.switchCode(id)`, React tries to find a property that's `switchCode`, which is not, but just a local variable. Replace the `this.props.switchCode(id)` with the above code.

Comment: thank you I did not that, thank you so much for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `console.log` with a `return` statement.

```
export   function switchCode (id){
switch(id){
    case 200:
    case 201:
    case 202:
    case 210:
    case 211:
    case 212:
    case 221:
    case 230:
    case 231:
    case 232: 
     return 'thunder_icon';
       break;

...
  }}
```